# How to process webcam images on nodejs using Posenet?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to process images from the WebCam using Posenet on the server-side, but I'm not sure how to pass the image data to the `estimateSinglePose`.

Below is the simplified version of the code;

**CLIENT**

```
const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 320, 180);
const buffer = imageData.data.buffer;
socket.emit("signal", buffer); //Pass it to the server through websocket
```

**BACKEND**

```
socket.on("signal", (data)=> {
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(data);
    const image = ts.tensor(data).reshape([180, 320, -1]);
    // this where I'm stuck, I don't know how to pass the image to the estimateSinglePose
})
```

**EDIT 1**

Passing it to the `estimateSinglePose` resulted in an error.

```
Error: Invalid TF_Status: 3

Message: Incompatible shapes: [193,257,4] vs. [3]
    at NodeJSKernelBackend.executeSingleOutput (/Users/xxx/app/server/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/nodejs_kernel_backend.js:209:43)
    at Object.kernelFunc (/Users/xxx/app/server/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/kernels/Add.js:28:24)
    at kernelFunc (/Users/xxx/app/server/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:3139:32)
    at /Users/xxx/app/server/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:3200:27
    at Engine.scopedRun (/Users/xxx/app/server/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:3012:23)
    at Engine.runKernelFunc (/Users/xxx/app/server/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:3196:14)
    at Engine.runKernel (/Users/xxx/app/server/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:3068:21)
    at add_ (/Users/xxx/app/server/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:8969:19)
    at Object.add__op [as add] (/Users/xxx/app/server/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:3986:29)
    at ResNet.preprocessInput (/Users/xxx/app/server/node_modules/@tensorflow-models/posenet/dist/resnet.js:41:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

`estimateSinglePose` takes as parameter an HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement. Server side with nodejs, you can use the package `canvas` to have the same behavior as the canvas in the browser

```
const posenet = require('@tensorflow-models/posenet');
const {Image, createCanvas} = require('canvas');
const canvas = createCanvas(img.width,img.height); // 180, 320
const ctx =  canvas.getContext('2d');

const net = await posenet.load();

socket.on("signal", async (data)=> {
    
    ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0)
  
     const pose = await net.estimateSinglePose(canvas, {
       flipHorizontal: false
     });

     // you can now use pose
   
})
```

Comment: I've tried that. It doesn't work, check the error above.

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid using node canvas, it's extremely slow. On TensorFlow there's a method called decodeImage, but I can't get it to work. https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-node/src/image.ts#L155

Comment: Looking at the estimateSinglePose signature, it does accept also ImageData. Maybe if using the canvas is slow, you can consider creating just an ImageData: const mydata = createImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(arraySize), width); I haven't tried to check if it is faster